# What is a good Unit Test Practice for mocking a fake model that changes a lot?

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, solid-principles

I'm trying to test this custom model where if some values are null, it wouldn't be a valid model. My custom model is defined in it's own class as:

```
public CustomModel(String FirstName, String LastName, String address, String phone)
```

...so on and so forth (there are more fields but we'll just use these for now as an example).

Now in my test, I create a dummy model by doing this (validator is a helper class that checks if it's null or not this is not important):

```
@Before
public void setUpBefore()
{
    _customTestModel = new CustomModel("First", "Last", "123 Address", "1234567890");
}
```

And then as a test example, I would do:

```
@Test
public void testNotValidModel_NullLastName()
{
    setUpBefore();
    _customTestModel.put(1, null);
    assertFalse(validator.test(null, _customTestModel));
}
```

My problem is, if I do need to change how I want to structure my custom model, say I want to do it like this now:

```
public CustomModel(String LastName, String FirstName, String phone, String address)
```

I would need to go back into my test and re-do my `_customTestModel` and also need to go into each of my tests and change the `.put(1, null)` to `.put(0, null)` to the proper slot.

I realize my test is very brittle and I would have to go into the test EVERY time I want to change the `customModel`. How should I go about fixing this?

Comment: Using a builder pattern rather than a constructor with a long parameter list might be useful - it gets you a little closer towards having named parameters. And what does the `.put()` method do? Positionally set a field to the specified value?

Comment: Oops, sorry, I didn't realize put was a helper method too -- it takes in an int field, and a value. It just takes which field to change for the model, and then will change the value accordingly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The *entire point* of type safety is that if you change the signature, you are required to change code that uses the signature. And the entire point of unit testing is that you call newly written code from the unit test. So if you change existing code, your client must break, and if you add new code, you must add a unit test for it. The system is working as intended.

Any solution I could give you is just a way to circumvent that. For example, you could retain the old constructors as legacy. Usually I prefer to keep my unit tests up to date rather than let them block getting rid of legacy code though.

If you had *production* clients who were in some sense complaining, then you would have a case for retaining legacy models, or adding a builder pattern, or some other solution. You would then need to define logic to maintain incomplete models and add even more unit test coverage to cover both the old and new code. But this is the opposite of what you are hoping for.

Comment: I see, I guess I misunderstood test coverage and got it backwards -- I thought a good test suite would never break no matter what you do to the code. I guess it makes sense if that you change the code logic and tests change, you should change the tests as well!

Comment: @m1771vw if the code logic changes, unit tests will test that the logic changes *only* in the intended way. You will notice that once you fix the constructor call in the smallest way possible, the unit test will still do its job in making sure there's no unintended side effects. My view on your problem is more that it's just too greedy to expect an API change and not have to do any work about it in your test code. One way to think of test code is it's your code's first client, like if you became a chocolate salesperson you would probably practice your pitch on your mom.